# Furnace Short Cycling - Carrier Code 33

Tags: heating, furnace

We have a Carrier 58STA/STX Furnace that is only short cycling in Heat and not A/C. When it cuts off it is throwing Code 33 which is pointing to the following issues:

- Dirty Filter or Restricted Duct System - Replaced Filters & Using a MERV 2, still trips
- Loose Blower Wheel - Removed today and was not loose/excessive play
- Defective Switch or Connections
- Defective Blower Motor or Capacitor - Capacitor was at 50% of nominal, replaced and still occurs, have not done anything with blower motor.
- Inadequate Combustion Air Supply (Flame Rollout Switch Open) - Flame Rollout Switch stays closed
- Restricted Vent Sizing - Spec'd to House
- Excessive Wind - Happens on Windy or Calm Days

If I either remove the filter or remove the blower access cover it does not throw the code.

Comment: Thank you for informing us of your situation. Is there a **question** you want to attach to your post.

Comment: Have you had the static pressure of your duct system measured? Has it always done this, or was there some event that prompted it to start doing this?

Comment: Was your system designed with a merv2 filter ? Your blower gains may be full of dust it is really wild that that slight curve can get a thick enough layer of dust / dirt to drop your flow / pressure.

Comment: We purchased the home in September of last year so this year was the first Winter with it. I don't recall it happening immediately but I also may have not noticed. I had used high MERV 4 - 7 and started dropping it as I noticed more issues.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out it was the Draft Safeguard that was tripping. After digging around online some more there were a couple recommendations:

Right when we purchased the home we redid the flooring immediately from linoleum that had a threshold at the closet to engineered hardwood and we did not put a threshold at the closet (effectively increasing the gap at the bottom). I both verified the intake was clear and also placed towels at the door gap and let the furnace run in which it finally did not short cycle.

Comment: Glad you were able to lick the issue!